# what is needed in order to use db.scan ()

Tags: ydn-db

I'm trying to get the scan function to work, but it seems i'm missing something: According to the documention this should work:

```
var iter = new ydn.db.KeyIterator('contact');
db.scan([iter], function(keys, values)
```

But every time i call the function i get the following error:

```
Uncaught ydn.error.ArgumentException: Iterator argument must be an array.
```

A contact sore with the name 'contact' exists and i tried different libraries ydb-db but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation is outdated. It should be:

```
db.scan(function(keys, values), [iter]
```

See [unit test](http://dev.yathit.com/test/test_algo.html) for it use case.